# Datagrid binding 2 datafiled under one column along with an image?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

here i am performing nested grid operation where in my first datagrid . have name,age,address

once user clicks the row we will be  showing another grid that is with data Subject name and Score

untill here the  functionality   works  fine .

1:now the Question is that i should be displaying an image along with score in the same  column( how can i achive this one)

2:Depending on the score i need to show an image( binding different image based on score)

```
1 :that is if score is 20 show ( ~images/image1.jpg)

2 :that is if score is 40 show ( ~images/image2.jpg)
```

3 :that is if score is 20 show (~images/ image3.jpg)

```
output [ in a grid  format]
 subject score  
 science  45 image3
 maths    50 image2
 Computer 60 image1
 general  78 image1
```

how  do we  solve this issue . any idea how  to go ahead. please let me know.
 hope  my question is clear

thanks in advance

prince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with Silverlight v4.0, I will assume that you are trying to accomplish this in said technology.  One way to accommplish this would be to add a converter as a static resource and then use said converter to pull in the data. For all intensive purposes, I am assuming that the image files are named with in the format imageX.jpg, where X is equal to the score, but you can use whatever format you prefer.  Please see below a untested, sample of XAML and C# code:

```
<USERCONTROL.RESOURCES>
    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <SvcTest:DSTest x:Key="DSTest" d:IsDataSource="True"/> 
<local:IDToImageConverter x:Key="IDToImageConverter"/> 
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Resources> 
<StackPanel x:Name="OurStack" Orientation="Vertical"> 
    <TextBox x:Name="InputText"/> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="OutputText"/> 
    <Button x:Name="CallServiceButton" Content="Call WCF" Click="CallServiceButton_Click"/> 
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="theDataGrid" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height=" 600" Width="800" CanUserResizeColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
        <data:DataGrid.Columns> 
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="InventTypeID" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding InventTypeID}" /> 
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ImageColumn" DisplayIndex="1" > 
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
<DataTemplate> 

<Image Source="{Binding ItemID, Converter={StaticResource IDToImageConverter}}" Height="50" /> 
</DataTemplate> 
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn> 
</data:DataGrid.Columns> 
</data:DataGrid> 
</StackPanel>
<?xml:namespace prefix = local /><local:IDToImageConverter x:Key="IDToImageConverter"></local:IDToImageConverter>
</USERCONTROL.RESOURCES>

    public class IDToImageConverter : IValueConverter 
    { 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
    Uri uri = new Uri("~/Images/" + value.ToString()+ ".jpg", UriKind.Relative); 
    return new BitmapImage(uri); 
    }

<GRID Background="White" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<STACKPANEL x:Name="OurStack" Orientation="Vertical">
<TEXTBOX x:Name="InputText" />
<TEXTBLOCK x:Name="OutputText" />
```

Comment: even this code  is written in  xaml only 
 public class IDToImageConverter : IValueConverter  
    {  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
    Uri uri = new Uri("~/Images/" + value.ToString()+ ".jpg", UriKind.Relative);  
    return new BitmapImage(uri);  
    } 
  or in a class file ?

Comment: You could write it inline, but I would recommend creating a separate class file.  I just put together something quickly for demonstration purposes.

Comment: thanks  for the  replay
even this  url help me out  to  solve the issue
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/181649.aspx

Comment: why are  we  using this 
 <SvcTest:DSTest x:Key="DSTest" d:IsDataSource="True"/> 

<?xml:namespace prefix = local /><local:IDToImageConverter x:Key="IDToImageConverter"></local:IDToImageConverter>

Comment: This was a demonstration of how the data could be pulled back via a service.  The lines that you are interested in are the c# code for the conversion and the image source line in the xaml.  The rest is just an example.